# If $A$ and $B$ are dualizable objects in a monoidal category, is the unit of the one duality the inverse of the counit of the other duality?

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around dualizable objects in monoidal categories and I was wondering whether the following claim holds:

Let $A$ and $B$ be dualizable objects in a monoidal category, i.e. $A \dashv B$ with unit $\eta : I \to B \otimes A$ and $B \dashv A$ with counit $\varepsilon' : B \otimes A \to I$.
Then $\eta \circ \varepsilon' = \text{id}_{B \otimes A}$.

I've been trying to manipulate the diagrams (triangle identities) in [this definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object#definition) to convince myself of my claim, but to no avail. I'm getting the suspicion that my claim is actually false. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a vector space $V$ over a field $k$ of finite dimension $n>1$. Then you are asking if a certain composite $V^*\otimes V\to k\to V^*\otimes V$ is the identity map. This cannot hold for reasons of dimension, so the claim is generally false.